# scanf error in C++ - program doesn't respond

Tags: c++, scanf

Okay that is weird. When I remove `int count = 1` and `count++;` from my code,
the program gives no error. Also if I remove `scanf` and do not remove
`count++;` program gives no error with `count++;`. They have nothing to do with
each other why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int IS_prime(int num) {
    int isprime = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i += 2) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            i++;

        if ((int(num) % i) == 0) {
            return isprime = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isprime;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 0;

    char *buffer;

    printf("Enter your sentence:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);

    char array[1000] = " ";
    char temp[2] = " ";

    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i] = buffer[i];
        a = array[i];
        int PrimeFind = IS_prime(a);

        if (a % 2 == 0) {

            printf("%c", a);
            // Do nothing
        } else if (PrimeFind == 0 && a % 1 == 0) {

            printf("%c", a);

            count++;
        } else {
            a++;
            temp[0] = a;
            printf("%c", a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code has nothign to do with c++. The formatting has to do with cat droppings.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?!? You're doing primality tests on the ASCII ordinal value of individual characters. That have not been initialized. This code does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes I know that is something my instructor want me to do. It is complicated. There is nothing wrong with the logic. It works fine. I only have problem with this scanf. It reads my input very well. but it conflicts with "count++;" and program is not responding.

Comment: too many errors dude, both in the programming and in the primality testing logic.

Comment: @TayfurGazioglu I'm going to let you take all the time you need to come to grips with [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and how computers have a tendency to just /do/ exactly what you tell them to. In this case you tell the computer to do random things, and  this is what you get.

Comment: `There is nothing wrong with the logic.` are you *sure*?

Comment: There is no error in the code. When I press run. It stops responding :(. That is what my instructor wants me to do.

Input string with length not exceeding 100 characters. Your task is to encrypt them according to the following criteria:
    1-if the character has an even value,
      -dont change it.
    2-if the character has a non prime odd value
      -add 1 to its value and get the corresponding character.
    3-if the character has prime odd value
      -initialize a count variable to 1 outside of the block,
       increment it inside the loop in each prime iteration.

Comment: `if ((int(num) % i) == 0) return isprime = 1;` ... nothing wrong with that?

Comment: Oh I was actually testing what causes the problem. I forgot to change it to "return isprime". Sorry @A.S.H

Comment: And when will you return 1?

Comment: Omg what is wrong with me I should have said "isprime = 1;" lol @A.S.H

Comment: The precious moment when someone has a very simple problem and yet replies with `There is nothing wrong with the logic. It works fine.` as if all the experienced programmers who look at the question have no idea what are they talking about and yet they are supposed to answer that...

Comment: @sehe: Yeah obviously nothing to do with C++. "`#include <string>`". Derp.

Comment: @sehe: _"because his ego is bruised"_. Let's leave out the personal attacks, eh? #flagged

Comment: I have mixed emotions. Am I happy that he solves it or am I sad that he is this guy http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/37834819.jpg

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think if you read the things well, you might find I'm reasonably balanced here. The comment might be "off-topic". But so are a lot of comments. We're people too.

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov I did not ask something like "Why my output is 5 instead 10 or something like that. My question was "why my program is not responding when i use scanf". I tested my codes and working as i wanted. Yeah. my code is not looks good and i know it. but it works. So there is nothing wrong with the logic!!!.

Comment: @sehe: _"His ego is bruised"_ is _never_ "reasonably balanced here". Check your privilege sir.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit give it a rest . I deleted that comment at least an hour before you came back to flame me some more. There's no pleasing everyone it seems.

Comment: @sehe I simply made the mistake of honestly replying to your most recent comment to me. Not "flaming". Gees calm down.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think I was reasonably balanced there, but you're free to disagree. Apparently your moral standards are higher than I realized.

Comment: @sehe: *shrug* If a belief that attacking someone's "bruised ego" on Stack Overflow to make your point is not a fair thing to do gives me high moral standards, then I'm happy to agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *buffer;

printf("Enter your sentence:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
```

`buffer` is not initialized there. It has a "random" value. (*indeterminate* is the technical term).

**UPDATE**

Just for fun, here's a C++ version:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc6703098949dbf)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

bool is_prime(int num) {
    if (num % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(num); i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {

    //// test your functions!
    // for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) { if (is_prime(i)) std::cout << i << " "; } return 0;

    std::cout << "Enter your sentence: ";
    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

        std::string encoded;

        size_t count = 0;

        std::transform(
            line.begin(), line.end(), 
            back_inserter(encoded),
            [&count] (uint8_t ch) -> char {
                if (ch % 2 == 0)
                    return ch; // Do nothing

                if (is_prime(ch) && ch % 2 == 1) {
                    count++;
                    return ch;
                } 

                return ch + 1;
            });

        std::cout << "Result: " << encoded << "\n";
        std::cout << "Count:  " << count   << "\n";
    }

}
```

When typing the sentence `The lazy cow jumped over the seedy moon!` the output is:

```
Enter your sentence: The lazy cow jumped over the seedy moon!
Result: The lazz dpx jvmped pver the teedz mppn"
Count:  9
```

Comment: I changed it to " char* buffer = " "; ". Still program not responding.

Comment: You're doing too many things wrong. What you get is **[Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** in many places. Can you answer my question in the comment at your question?

Comment: @TayfurGazioglu You want `char buffer[200]`.

Comment: @user3386109 that's a drop in the ocean, really (also, bad advice for picking `200` without limiting the scanf format string accordingly). There are so many follow up questions that I can't even imagine how to fix without knowing the goal. But you know, OP is convinced "There is nothing wrong with the logic.". And the "`scanf` is reading the input very well". Well, in that case, we will probably never know...

Comment: @user3386109 Just for kicks, I've added a [c++ interpretation of that comment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc6703098949dbf).

Comment: Wow man. It gives the same output as my code. But yours is much more efficient.( I think yours is little bit advanced for me :)) )  Thank you. @sehe

Comment: Cheers. I hope it just inspires you. No need to adopt any code you don't understand (in fact, that's a bad idea always). But, the thing to take away is that you should always think about what you /want/ your code to look like, and what tools exist to achieve that. Code forgery is a craft.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this fixed the problem.

I changed this:

```
char *buffer;

printf("Enter your sentence:\n");
scanf("%[^\n]", buffer);
```

To this:

```
char buffer[100] = " ";

printf("Enter your sentence:\n"); 
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
```

Something is wrong with "scanf" but I could not figure out. fgets is working perfectly. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: +1 for `fgets` which is already a lot safer than `scanf` (unless you use the extended format strings which allow length limits too). Anyways, in case you were still interesting in a C++ solution, see my answer, based on [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446757/scanf-error-in-c-program-doesnt-respond/33446765#comment54681809_33446757)

Comment: @Tayfur `Something is wrong with "scanf" ` are you being serious..?